# Selectively building gtest tests with cmake and showing gtest output

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, build-automation, googletest

I've got cmake working with a test file similar to " [How to start working with GTest and CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507723/how-to-start-working-with-gtest-and-cmake) " but the problem is that gtest and the test binary gets built each time I make rather than just when I run make test. And when running make test, only the ctest summary output is shown, not the actual gtest output.
How can I change this behaviour so that the tests and gtest library is only built when I run make test, and running make test actually shows the proper output?

Comment: My bad, should have done more searching...

Solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609692/building-tests-with-cmake-while-not-using-ctest?rq=1

Comment: Did you find out how to show the output from gtest instead of or as well as the output from ctest?

Comment: There's two ways of doing it, first is simply not to use test and have a different target like `check` instead that will compile and run the gtest main program, the other is to use a script that will compile each test separately and for ctest to then run each gtest individually, so that `make test` will also work (but will produce CTest-style output rather than `check` which is directly from GTest). To see how I did it, look at https://github.com/adammw/hit3172/blob/case_study/swin-adventure/test/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: With Add_executable you can generate .exe(test.exe) file for the gtest test cases . And run the [test.exe --gtest_output=xml:"%CD%\test.xml"] command from command line will generate the gtest output in the xml file.